# Ошибка : tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
 print ("Для начала , найдём первую ёмкость ")
 print ("Введи данные первой ёмкости ")
  h = float(input('Введи высоту цилиндра , в первой ёмкости '))
  dm = float(input('Введи диаметр цилиндра , в первой ёмкости '))
  R = int(input('Радиус конца с сегментами '))
  V1 = int(input('Объём заполняемого '))
  konc = int(input('Концетрация '))
  potr = float(input('Потребность в производстве '))
  plt = float(input('Плотность вещества '))
  tsm = int(input('Часов в смене '))
  pi = float(input('Чему равно PI '))
  print ('Рассчитаем массу ёмкости и кол-во смен ')
  print ('Решение')
  rcc = dm/2
  rc = float(rcc)
 print(rc ,'м - радиус цилиндра')
  D = float(R*2)
 print(D ,'м - диаметр сегментов')
  H11 =((D-dm)**2 - (D-dm)/2)
  H1 = float(H11)
  H = math.sqrt(H1)
 print = (H ,' - Высота усечённого конуса')
  Vcil = pi*(rc**2)*h
 print (Vcil,' - объём цилиндрической части')
  Vseg = pi * H * (R**2 + R*rc + rc**2)
  print (Vseg , " - объём сегментивной части")
  Vem = Vcil + 2*Vseg
 print (Vem, " - Объём емкости")
  Vzap = Vem * (V1/100)
 print (Vzap,' - объём запасов')
 print ('Теперь , найдём объём латекса')
  Vlat = Vzap * (konc/100)
 print (Vlat,'m^3 - обём латекса')
 print ('Теперь , найдём массу латекса')
  m1 = plt * Vlat
 print (m1,'кг - масса латекса')
  Qsm = potr * tsm
 print (Qsm,' - Расход латекста за смену')
  Nsm = Vlat / Qsm
 print (Nsm, '- Колличество смен')
```

При компиляции пишет , что на 25 строке произошёл косяк : tuple object is not callable , перед этим должно вывести H

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в строке опечатка:

```
print = (H ,' - Высота усечённого конуса')
```

Должно быть:

```
print(H ,' - Высота усечённого конуса')
```

Таким образом, Вы создаёте переменную `print` и присваиваете ей кортеж `(H ,' - Высота усечённого конуса')`, из-за этого в дальнейшем происходит ошибка.

Comment: Глаз-алмаз :) эта опечатка такая незаметная :)

Comment: Ты прав , спасибо